# .htaccess Excluding multiple files from rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with a rewrite.

I have come this far as of yet.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$-[L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have five files(tc.php, tc__.php, tc_activate.php, tcused.php and tcvalid.php) that I do not want to be written over to https. Or rather, I do not want them to be hit with this rule at all. And I have no idea why it continues to overwrite anyways.

Edit: this is the whole rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /folderName/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folderName/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$-[L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does what you don't wanna do :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$-[L]
```

Above line will match not exclude so the flag is wrong so, make it like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$ [NC]
```

So your all code will be like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear your browser cache before testing this code

> Update:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /folderName/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folderName/(.*)$  /folderName/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folderName/(tc|tc__|tc_activate|tcused|tcvalid)\.php$
RewriteRule ^folderName/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/folderName/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I tried changing it and it still writes over, eventhough I clear the browser cache. It now looks like this(see edit):

Comment: please see update and make sure you change it accordingly

Comment: The specific files are not written over to https. But I can't reach any other page on the site. /about gives a 404. It's a wordpress site, if it makes any difference?

Comment: save these two lines out and test the code agin after clearing browser cache RewriteBase /folderName/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: Same issue remains as the previous comment, unfortunately.